# Cucumber: usage file in scenario

Tags: java, cucumber, integration-testing

I have the following scenario:

```
Feature: Some feature
   Scenario: Test feature
     Given login as test_user
     When test_user submits changes with content:
        """
        Very long text
        """
     Then content is saved
```

The main goal is to move the "very long text" to some file or something like this and avoid duplication of this text in the defined scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I see only one solution (this solution  isn't so nice, but can be used as alternative):

```
Feature: Some feature
   Scenario: Test feature
     Given login as test_user
     When test_user submits changes with content very_long_text.txt            
     Then content is saved
```

And put very_long_text.txt in the project test resources. Separate folder can be created to hold all cucumber resources. As example: src/test/resources/cucumber

And create Utility class that read content of this resource:

```
public static String getText(String fileName){
    IOUtils.toString("cucumber" + fileName);
}
```

And use the file content in  that way. In order to do not duplicate messages in the code